# CSS3 rotateY without transitions applied

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm looking for a simple way to take an object and transform its rotateY property without it animating to its pre-set transition. [This will help me complete this slide show](http://3stepsforward.org.uk/html5/3d-slideshow/) (ONLY VIEW IN CHROME OR SAFARI (WEBKIT))

Here's a breakdown example of the effect:

**CSS** - Transition is set to 5s

**Phase1**

*Element1* - rotateY:0;

*Element2* - rotateY:-180;

**User** - clicks button

**Phase2**

*Element1* - rotateY:180;

*Element2* - rotateY:0;

**Phase3**

*Element1* - rotateY:-180;

*Element2* - rotateY:0;

**User** - clicks button

**Phase4**

*Element1* - rotateY:0;

*Element2* - rotateY:180;

After first transition (phase1 & 2) completes the rotateY value of *Element1* needs to be set to -180 without a transition so that it's in the position *Element2* was in in Phase1. With this the animation will make the elements appear to spin around one another as you can see on the example link I have supplied. Unfortunately the effect ceases after all elements have their rotateY:180;

I'd like to do a jsFiddle but I really haven't time right now on this project.

**I need a solution that simply takes the object from point a to b without any animation/transition**

Hope that all makes sense

Comment: I am sorry Richard. I just don't understand what you want. The slideshow link you have provided looks great. In simple terms what part are you trying to change about the way it works.

Comment: here's is a jsFiddle example [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/2XU7D/21/. It's not totally true to my concept but _hopefully_ it'll illustrate the problem. The **test** element is set to `rotateY:180;` initially. Then onClick should go to `rotateY:90;` with `-webkit-transition:0;` and the to `rotateY:0;` with `-webkit-transition:.5s;` . But it fails and I assume it's due to the code not being able to act before it's overwriting with the latter. It's a crude example I know :)

Comment: sorry use this link instead [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/2XU7D/25/

Comment: Thanks tw16 that worked. Here it is modified to replicate what I was after http://jsfiddle.net/2XU7D/28/. I tried to solve my issue in that fashion before (using timeouts) but it didn't work for me within my current project. I guess I should have gone back to basics and watched it work on a simpler level as now I feel it can be incorporated in some way! It's to easy to get bogged down in issues I guess. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Here is the final execution http://www.3stepsforward.org.uk/html5/3d-slideshow/

Comment: It is looking very good! But don't forget to make it compatible with other browsers at least on a more basic level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to rotate an object without a transition, then you should not be setting a transition at all. Only set the transform:

```
$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotateY(180deg)');

$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotateY(0)');
```

Live example to show no transition when rotated: http://jsfiddle.net/2XU7D/4/

Comment: By "use the correct syntax", you mean `rotate(180deg)` rather than `rotateY(180deg)` ? In fact, `rotate(x, y)` is a shortcut for `rotateX(x); rotateY(y);`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/, point 6.

Comment: @johnny5: You are right and wrong as it happens. Look at [Point 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-functions) of your link, and you will see it provides the same syntax as I have given. `rotateX` and `rotateY` are used for 3d transforms http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/#transform-functions not 2d (which is what your link went to). But thank you it hadn't occurred to me that he was doing a 3d transform, as I mostly use Firefox which doesn't support them.

Comment: I have edited my questions above to hopefully make things clear :)

Comment: @richard: I am happy to see it worked for you. And yes, going back to basics can often help overcome what might seem like huge issues.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do one thing, creates two classes:

```
.enable{ -webkit-transform : rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transition : 10s; }
.disable{ -webkit-transform : rotateY(0deg); -webkit-transition : 0; }
```

and checks the class you want the event.

Comment: Using classes didn't work. I should have taken your post in more and realised you were reiterating that I could do what I've already done with classes.

I've also updated my problem above.