# Set css rotateY without animation

Tags: css, rotation, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm making a flipcard html element which rotates around the Y axis when clicked. That part works well enough although someone has spotted a bug where occasionally the content on the 'reverse' of the flipcard ends up mirror-imaged along the y axis (I've established this is because the browser gets held up by a SCORM update and misses the y rotation). 
My proposed 'solution' is to reset the y rotation to 0 when the initial 'flip' transition completes. The problem is I can't find how to simply SET the y rotation, without it transitioning/animation to that rotation. **I'd just like to set the y rotation immediately, without any animation.**

This answer...
[CSS3 rotateY without transitions applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849005/css3-rotatey-without-transitions-applied)
... says I shouldn't use transition, just transform, but that's exactly what I'm doing:

```
$("#card"+element.attr('id')).css({ '-webkit-transform' : 'rotateY( 0deg)', '-moz-transform' : 'rotateY( 0deg)', '-o-transform' : 'rotateY( 0deg)', 'transform' : 'rotateY( 0deg)' });
```

I've also tried:

```
$("#card"+element.attr('id')).css({ '-webkit-transform' : 'matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)', '-moz-transform' : 'matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)', '-o-transform' : 'matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)', 'transform' : 'matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)' });
```

In the css there IS a transition defined:

```
.flipcard.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    transform: rotateY( 180deg);
    padding: 30px;
}

.flipcard {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;    
    transition: transform 3500ms ease;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    min-height:480px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

...so is that also affecting any other transform that's added to the element? To be honest I'm new to CSS transitions so I'm not 100% sure how that initial flip transition is even being applied.

Once again, any help will be much appreciated!

**EDIT**
To clarify: I'm trying to reset the rotateY property via a setTimeout function that is triggered when the cardflip element is first clicked. Here's how it looks at the moment:

```
setTimeout(function(){
                        console.log("Rotation should reset to 0?");
                        $("#card"+element.parent().attr('id')).css({ '-webkit-transition-property' : 'none !important', '-moz-transition-property' : 'none !important', '-o-transition-property' : 'none !important', 'transition-property' : 'none !important' });
                        $("#card"+element.parent().attr('id')).css({ '-webkit-transform' : 'rotateY( 0deg)', '-moz-transform' : 'rotateY( 0deg)', '-o-transform' : 'rotateY( 0deg)', 'transform' : 'rotateY( 0deg)' });
                    }, 3600);
```

The delay is a little longer than the rotation animation. The problem with this solution is subsequent 'flips' on other cards get messed up (I'm assuming because the transition properties are now set not to be changed). **I'd just like to set the rotateY property of a clicked card flip to 0 when the iniial 'flip' animation has completed, without animating to the new value.** Surely that's straightforward.

Comment: This is called transition. So remove `transition: transform 3500ms ease;` from `.flipcard { }`

Comment: @Akash Pinnaka - But don't I need that transition to perform the initial 'flip'? If I take that line out there is no animation on the 'flip'. How can I have an animation on the initial flip, and then set rotateY WITHOUT any animation?

Comment: You can do that using Javascript. Here is how. After window load, Add class `no-flip` to the elements. And in CSS give `.no-flip { transition-property: none !important } `. Make sure of cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: @Akash Pinnaka - I tried your suggestion, although I've implemented it via a 'setTimeOut' triggered when the card is first clicked with a delay a little longer than the length of the 'flip' animation. For testing purposes, I've reduced the flip rotation to 100degress (so I can see when the rotateY is reset) and it does not appear to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @moosefetcher Hello, you could have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42148531/7100628

Comment: @moosefetcher From what I understand from your question, you want to make the transition instant upon `mouseout`, for that you will need to apply the transition on the `element`, and apply the initial transition(with duration) on the `element:hover`. Does [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/wauLkbxp/3/) help at all?

Comment: @SirExotic - I don't want the rotation 'reset' applied on mouseout; I'm adding it to circumvent the possibility of the cardflip content ending up horizontally inverted (because of the browser getting 'distracted' during a SCORM update). The initial flip happens when the cardflip element is clicked; I'd like to set the rotateY to 0 when the flip animation has completed. At the moment I'm doing that via a setTimeout with a delay a little longer than the time of the flip animation. I hope that clears it up a bit...

Comment: I think I understand. Beside a transition-duration there is also [**transition-delay**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay). I think that would work instead of a setTimeout, no?

Comment: @SirExotic - I'm getting the impression I need to set up 2 transitions; One for the actual card-flip animation and another for the instantaneous rotate reset to 0. Is that at least conceptually correct?

Comment: Are you looking for the effect on card3 in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/wauLkbxp/4/)? There is a transition-duration and delay on hover, but on mouseout there is only a transition-duration.

Comment: @SirExotic - Sorry - all I see on the fiddle is a bouncing blue cloud (!) But I don't want anything triggered by hover or mouse out. I want everything triggered by one click; First the 180 degree rotation, then - to check that the content on the 'reverse' of the card isn't backwards once the flip animation completed - a rotateY reset back to 0.